# Is it alright to favor the winners on a list?

Tags: discussion

Some one asked for a list of 3D XNA engines so I researched and made a list. Then I went thru each one, and found the most practical and therefore the best ones and put them on top, with pictures. This is favoring the better engines, simply because they are a better choice to make. I'm not affiliated to any one so I'm a neutral third party.

Is it alright to "promote" the winners and list everyone else at the bottom of lists?

[View the list here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5135/3d-game-engines-for-xna-games/5253#5253)

Comment: The site isn't exactly a promotion site - people want what's best for them, not a random one to first catch their eye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely.  Just putting together a list of things by itself is useful (although whether it's better than a simple google search or pointing to some premade wiki page with the same data is arguable), but not nearly as useful as providing some guidance along with it.

Then again I seem to be in the weird camp who thinks that "lists of whatever" are better served as individual answers so that people can vote and discuss individual points better than just having a singular data dump.

Answer (score 1):

I think its okay as long as you've made a fair judgment based on a comparison of the entries.

I saw your update and its quite nice to see someone do my homework :)..  Typically you have to get your head into 100 products when they're listed down. If you think you have the expertise to rate and judge entries **neutrally** then I think its great to let you do the comparison once and for all.

BTW, I'm the OP of the question so I'm biased towards thinking your work is good, because it really helped me :) ... I was going to go with the Torque X 3D engine and I'd even finalized with my financial team. Luckily I noticed your comment (and other comments) that it wasn't the way to go so now I have another alternative (based on your "top list")